# Shared folder on Windows 10 machine takes ages to access and do anything

Tags: windows-10, networking, network-shares

I have a simple server in my network running Windows 10, that I'm planning to use as a network storage for users to save and access files via Windows shares on LAN. I already have a computer serving the exact purpose, but I need to migrate it to the mentioned server due to security concerns and disk space.

I made the shares on the server, granted permissions, and so I tried to test it out. For some reason, accessing the share takes like 2-5 minutes of loading, and then doing anything in the shared spaces takes 5 minutes also, like entering a folder, opening a file, even typing a letter in Notepad. These problems persist no matter which machine I access it from. I checked the antivirus we use, but it's not blocking anything, connection shouldn't be an issue because I'm connecting to the server remotely and there is no problems with responsiveness/speed. What do I do?

Comment: How many users are we talking here?  Windows 10 was not designed to be a server OS and, while having some such capabilities, is not tuned to be.

Comment: It's for documents only, usually no more than a megabyte each, and while we have about 20 workstations that are gonna have access to it, those are usually spaced-out, single and very quick transactions. As I said, we're already running it on Windows 10, and it works fine, but we want to move it to a dedicated machine.

Comment: Fair enough.  Sometimes people ask about serving hundreds of users with a client edition so wanted to make sure.  Typing in Notepad is effected?  On all machines?  Notepad uses local memory buffers and does not create temp files or anything that would touch the share unless actively opening or saving a file.  Can you reproduce that behavior reliably?  Does it still happen if you disconnect the share?

Comment: Yes, it is, 2-5 minutes to access the machine, then another to enter the share, then another to see the test .txt file, another to open it with notepad, and then even a keystroke takes a minute or two. It persists after restarting the machine, and it's that machine only.